How can I put variables in a separate list after in the for loop?
I was given the task to write a function that will search for the maximum average score of students, I got to the point where the code outputs the average score of each student. but I don't know how to find the maximum. I tried to put it in the "list", but it didn't work
students = [
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "grades": [5, 5, 4, 4]},
    {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Doe", "grades": [4, 3, 4, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Bill", "surname": "Gates", "grades": [5, 5, 5, 3]},
    {"name": "Steve", "surname": "Jobs", "grades": [3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Guido", "surname": "Van Rossum", "grades": [5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Elon", "surname": "Musk", "grades": None}
]


for i in students:
    if i['grades'] == None:
            print('this is zero')
    else:
        len_list = len(i['grades'])
        sum_list = sum(i['grades'])
        average_list = (round(sum_list / len_list,1))
        my_list = []
        my_list.append(average_list)
        print(average_list)

Outputs just 6 numbers, each of which is in a separate "list".

Move my_list = [] outside of the loop to put all averages in same list. Then, use the builtin max() function to find the maximum average.
like:
my_list = []

for i in students:
    if i['grades'] == None:
        print('this is zero')
    else:
        len_list = len(i['grades'])
        sum_list = sum(i['grades'])
        average_list = (round(sum_list / len_list,1))
        my_list.append(average_list)
        print(average_list)

max_avg = max(my_list)
print(f"Max is: {max_avg}")


The built-in max() function allows you to specify a function that provides the actual values needed in the assessment of the highest value.
With these data you could do this:
from statistics import mean

students = [
    {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "grades": [5, 5, 4, 4]},
    {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Doe", "grades": [4, 3, 4, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Bill", "surname": "Gates", "grades": [5, 5, 5, 3]},
    {"name": "Steve", "surname": "Jobs", "grades": [3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Guido", "surname": "Van Rossum", "grades": [5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5]},
    {"name": "Elon", "surname": "Musk", "grades": None}
]

def calc(d):
    nums = d.get("grades")
    return 0. if nums is None else mean(nums)

print(max(students, key=calc))

Output:
{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'grades': [5, 5, 4, 4]}

Note:
Similarly, the built-in sorted() function also allows for a key function. The same function shown in this answer could therefore be used to sort the list. e.g.,
print(*sorted(students, key=calc), sep="\n")

Sorted output:
{'name': 'Elon', 'surname': 'Musk', 'grades': None}
{'name': 'Jane', 'surname': 'Doe', 'grades': [4, 3, 4, 3, 5]}
{'name': 'Steve', 'surname': 'Jobs', 'grades': [3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5]}
{'name': 'Guido', 'surname': 'Van Rossum', 'grades': [5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5]}
{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'grades': [5, 5, 4, 4]}
{'name': 'Bill', 'surname': 'Gates', 'grades': [5, 5, 5, 3]}

